# How to compare data fetched from database and get the biggest value of that particular row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$vote1="SELECT * FROM vote_details_urban WHERE booth_id = '$booth_id' AND year = '$year' ";
$rsvote1=mysqli_query($con,$vote1);
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsvote1)) {
    $value1=$row1["party1"];
    $value2=$row1["party2"];
    $value3=$row1["party3"];
    $value4=$row1["party4"];
    $value5=$row1["party5"];
    $value6=$row1["party6"];
    $value7=$row1["party7"];
    $value8=$row1["party8"];
    $value9=$row1["party9"];
    $value10=$row1["party10"];
    $value11=$row1["party11"];
    $value12=$row1["party12"];
    $value13=$row1["party13"];
    $value14=$row1["party14"];
    $value15=$row1["party15"];
    $value16=$row1["party16"];
    $value17=$row1["party17"];
    $value18=$row1["party18"];
    $value19=$row1["party19"];
    $value20=$row1["party20"];
}
```

What I'm trying to do is finding the biggest value from all the above values and also find the difference between `$row1["party1"];` and the biggest value and also find the difference between `$row1["party1"];` and `$row1["party2"];`

So that i can display the result in the table below in such a way that if party1 has more vote than winner than it should show +value and if less -value. Similarly when comparing part1 with party2 whose result i want to show in 2nd column

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead><tr><th>Winner Party</th>
<th>Difference From Winner Party</th>
<th>Difference From Party2</th>  
</tr></thead><tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: See: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the function [max()](http://php.net/max), it takes an array and returns the highest element in the array, for example `max([20, 30, 40, 1, 3, 4])` returns 40. You would get the maximum value and then subtract it from party1 or party2, if you also intend to get the array key a simple solution would be using [array_search()](http://php.net/array-search) on the value returned by max

Comment: is there a way i can identify which column has the biggest value so that i can display the name of the winning party? @thelmuxkriovar

Comment: array_search could help you with that